# Can the damping coefficient of a pendulum be predicted given physical variables?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, harmonic-oscillator, drag, data

I'm aware you're able to calculate the coefficient of damping, $b$, given a set of amplitudes over time through $$\ln(\theta/\theta_0) = -bt/2$$ However, is there any way to get $b$ without empirical data? I've tried to get $b$ through force analysis the drag equation by having $$F_d = -bv$$ but the value of $b$ differed from my own empirical calculations every time (although I may have made a mistake). I've ruled out SHM and energy analysis for obvious reasons; is there any other way to calculate $b$?

Answer (score 1):

It is but it is usually not easy to do and often results in numerical computation rather than an analytic solution.

Stokes' law is an example of an analytic solution with the drag force being given by $6\pi r v \eta$ for a sphere of radius $r$, travelling through a fluid of viscosity $\eta$ at a speed $v$.
However in the derivation of this formula a number of assumptions need to be made:
Stokes' law makes the following assumptions for the behavior of a particle in a fluid: The object i spherical, with a smooth surface and it is travelling through fluid of infinite extent of viscosity with the flow being lamina.

The Wikipedia [Stokes' law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law) has a derivation of the relationship.

If a dimensionless parameter called Reynold's number, $\dfrac {\rho v r}{\eta}$, where $\rho$ is the density of the fluid, is less than one you can assume that the flow is laminar and so Stokes' law is valid.

So perhaps you can use this relationship for a simple pendulum with a spherical bob ignoring the [drag due to the string](https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=73856), which of course may be significant?